# Who or what is Ghostrider?

Tags: top-gun

In Top Gun there is the iconic line

> Negative Ghostrider the pattern is full.

I’m assuming that “the pattern” is some kind of air traffic control flight plan meaning there’s no space to fly past the tower.

However, who or what is Ghostrider? It’s neither Maverick nor Goose’s real names so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The VF-142 Ghostriders was Maverick and Goose's fighter squadron, and Ghostrider is the callsign for their specific plane for that reason.

If you pay attention at the beginning, you'll see that Cougar's aircraft has callsign Ghostrider 1, and Maverick's plane is Ghostrider 2. These callsigns designate the aircraft, not the crew, and they derive from the squadron name. They do not use their individual callsigns (i.e., Maverick, Goose, Cougar, or Merlin) for three reasons:

- Immediate clarity: by using the squadron callsign, other aviators know who's being addressed. For instance, if a plane from a different carrier or squadron hears "Maverick is thirty seconds out," he may not know who Maverick is. But if he hears "Ghostrider 2 is thirty second out," he knows an F-14 is on the way.
- Operational security: if the enemy has collected intelligence on specific individuals (and they do), they do not want to telegraph on the radio exactly who is in the air, or even who is still in what squadron.
- An F-14 has a crew of two, each one with a callsign. Therefore the aircraft callsign alerts both crewman that they are being addressed.

At Topgun, Maverick and Goose are the only ones from their squadron there and therefore the callsign for any aircraft they fly is Ghostrider (no number because there is only one). This is why Maverick's plane is addressed as Ghostrider when he requests to buzz the tower.

Comment: From the [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/TopGun.html) - *"The Ghost Riders enter. The place is on fire: a mob of dancers, flashing lights, blaring HARD ROCK MUSIC. Beer flows. Pilots talk flying and hustle girls."*

Answer (score -1):

It's the name of the fighter squadron - the group of planes Maverick, Goose etc are part of.

Comment: IMO, its the name of the aircraft, not the squadron. If it was the squadron, the command bridge on the carrier wouldn't have made the distinction between Mustang and Ghost Rider. I do agree that Ghost Rider was the name of a defunct IRL fighter squadron though.